# Column displayed on top of other column Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem with my grid system in Bootstrap. I have the following structure:

```
<div class="container content">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2 side-nav">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8 matchview">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 ">
             TEST
        </div>
  </div>
```

The last part containing the word TEST is displayed on top of the right side-nav. The right side-nav has a fixed position, anybody an idea why this happends and what would fix this?

```
.matchview{
position: fixed;
left: 200px;
height: calc(100% - 100px);
overflow-y: scroll;
```

}

```
.side-nav{
position: absolute;
width: 200px;
overflow-y: scroll;
top: 105px;
bottom: 0;
padding: 0;
text-align: center;
opacity: 77%;
color: #485563 !important;
```

}

The matchview has the left margin of 200px; to not conflict with the side-nav. It is a bit of a mess and does not work well for responsiveness neither. The reason why I have the position of the side-nav fixed is because there is a top header of 105px and if I change the positioning I lose the header on scroll.

Comment: What do you want to fix?

Comment: can you show us your css of **side-nav** and **matchview** class?

Comment: I added this to the description

Answer (score 1):

Elements with a fixed position are displayed at a fixed location on the screen. The do not influence the flow of the rest of your website and depending on your z-indexes they can overlay other elements or be overlayed. You will need to reserve the space your fixed side-nav needs, otherwise static elements will move behind or in front of it.

Comment: Is there a way to do this with something similar to clearfix?

Comment: No, a clearfix will not help you here. If I understand correctly your nav has a fixed position at the right side of the screen. So to prevent elements from moving underneath that nav you could just wrap all your other content in a div that is as wide as the body minus the nav. CSS `calc(100% - 20px)` will help you with that.

Comment: Okay I added a calculated margin left now, which solves the issue somewhat, thanks

Answer (score 0):

In `Bootstrap` every `row` are divided into `12` `columns`. You can divided this 12 columns in any combination. In your code, you have divided `2+8+2` combination. In the last 2 columns you have wrote `TEST`. If you give color then it will be clear to you.

```
<div class="container content">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2 side-nav" style="background: red;">
        DIV COL-MD-2
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8 matchview" style="background: orange;">
        DIV COL-MD-8
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 " style="background: green;">
             TEST
     </div>
</div>
```

[image]